# Display data, one object element at a time in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In a basic table structure, I want to be able to display a set of data from an array of objects one at a time. Clicking on a button or something similar would display the next object in the array.

The trick is, I don't want to use the visible tag and just hide the extra data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you can just specify property that indicate the current element you want to display and index of that element inside your `observableArray` .. i have made simple demo check it out.

```
<div id="persons"> <span data-bind="text: selectedPerson().name"></span>
    <br/>
    <button data-bind="click: showNext" id="btnShowNext">Show Next</button>
    <br/>
</div>
```

//here is the JS code

```
function ViewModel() {
    people = ko.observableArray([{
        name: "Bungle"
    }, {
        name: "George"
    }, {
        name: "Zippy"
    }]);
    showNext = function (person) {
        selectedIndex(selectedIndex() + 1);
    };
    selectedIndex = ko.observable(0);
    selectedPerson = ko.computed(function () {
        return people()[selectedIndex()];
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

kindly check this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/HwCPz/)**

Comment: Thanks, the example helped me develop a good solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Create observable property for a single object, then when clicking next just set that property to other object and UI will be updated.